# How save to array of values in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

Below is my coding to save message for each phone number inside the array
In the test i have set message as **welcome to all and 5 phone number**s into SMSDTO

How do i save **welcome to all**  message for each phone number in database

1   welcome to all  9964289813
2   welcome to all  9593754589
3   welcome to all  9964289444
4   welcome to all  9964458454

**Pojo class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sms")
public class SMSDTO {
    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "j", strategy = "increment")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "j")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "message")
    private String message;
    @Column(name = "phoneNumber")
    private String[] phonenumebr;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String[] getPhonenumebr() {
        return phonenumebr;
    }

    public void setPhonenumebr(String[] phonenumebr) {
        this.phonenumebr = phonenumebr;
    }

}
```

**Main class**

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SMSDTO sms = new SMSDTO();
    String [] sArry=new String[] { "9964289813", "9591237001", "8722922982", "9611704698", "9900598503" };  
    Configuration c = new Configuration();
    c.configure("/hibernate.cfg.xml");
    SessionFactory sf = c.buildSessionFactory();
    Session s = sf.openSession();
    Transaction tx = s.beginTransaction();
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < sArry.length; i++) {
            sms.setMessage("welcome to All");
            sms.setPhonenumebr(sArry[i]);
            s.save(sms);
        }

        tx.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        tx.rollback();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Replace the array with a single String and create one `SMSDTO` for each combination of number and message (= 5 total) instead of one.

Comment: thats just an example for 5

Comment: Yes, it is generally advisable to model the entity classes that each entity represents one row in the database. Your model contains a list of values which does not represent your desired database structure.

Answer (score 0):

Change your **POJO** class as below:

```
private String phonenumebr;

public String getPhonenumebr() {
    return phonenumebr;
}
public void setPhonenumebr(String phonenumebr) {
    this.phonenumebr = phonenumebr;
}
```

Just change the `private String[] phonenumebr;` to `private String phonenumebr;` because you have an array of String and later you are setting a single value of phoneNumber in Main program . This can be stored using String type of phonenumebr, Since String is an array of characters.

Change your **Main** method as below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Session session = null;
    Transaction tx = null;
    try {

        Configuration c = new Configuration();
        c.configure("/hibernate.cfg.xml");
        SessionFactory sf = c.buildSessionFactory();
        session = sf.openSession();

        SMSDTO sms =null;
        String [] sArry=new String[] { "9964289813", "9591237001", "8722922982", "9611704698", "9900598503" };  
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        for (int i = 0; i < sArry.length; i++) {
            sms= new SMSDTO();
            sms.setMessage("welcome to All");
            sms.setPhonenumebr(sArry[i]);
            session.save(sms);
        }
        tx.commit();

    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        try {
            tx.rollback();
        } catch (RuntimeException rbe) {
            System.err.println("Couldn’t roll back transaction"+ rbe);
       }
        throw e;
    } finally{
        if(session != null){
            session.close();
        }
    }

    System.out.println("entries saved...");
}
```

**Output**:

[image: Output]

Comment: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: sms, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(phoneNumber)]

Comment: you need to add @OneToMany mapping for mapping a List with DB. Here is a full example http://www.javatpoint.com/list-one-to-many. Using annotation then use this, https://dzone.com/tutorials/java/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-one-to-many-using-annotations-1.html here instead of list they have used Set, so that there cannot be duplicate phoneNumbers

Comment: This is also good example http://www.javatpoint.com/mapping-list-in-collection-mapping becauz your phoneNumber is not a class. Here, in Question class -> private List<String> answers;

Comment: i no need of maaping

Comment: Will come back to you soon.

Comment: i have changed my Test class that saving last phone number and message into database

Comment: ya but last phone number only saved not all numbers

Comment: SMSDTO sms = new SMSDTO(); should be inside the for-loop, since only one sms object is created and its phonenumber is set as the last index of array.

Comment: Nothing change same last phone number only saved in database

Comment: put your suggestion in answer

Comment: Nothing change same last phone number only saved in database

Comment: It should work, replace your entire main program with new one and change the phoneNumber frim POJO as in snapshot. Run the program in debug mode and check what data is set to sms object at session.save(sms); Let me know how many objects are stored in database?

Comment: can you get me the mail id please

Comment: 5 objects are stored in database

Comment: and the numbers? are they same as in output?

Comment: yes... please get me the mail i have some doubts in hibernate

Comment: If you have value setted object then the old values will be overridden by the new ones.